# High quality image re-sampling in Mono/C#/ASP.NET

Tags: linux, image-processing, mono, image-manipulation

I've developed a site that requires high quality resizing of uploaded photos.  The site works perfectly under ASP.NET on Windows. This afternoon I tried running it under Mono/Apache/Ubuntu 10.10. To my surprise, it worked - except for the image resampling.

It seems the libraries underlying Mono's Graphics/GDI+ implementation don't implement the bi-cubic interpolation mode.  (See [Mono Ignores Graphics.InterpolationMode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685084/mono-ignores-graphics-interpolationmode) ).

So I'm looking for a library that can do high quality image resizing.  I'm willing to put in the effort to interop to it from C# since this is important functionality and I'd like to be able to run under mono if at all possible.  I don't really need any other graphics processing capabilities - just resize.

Follow up: as suggested below ImageMagick works really well for this and was pretty easy to interop to.  More details here: http://www.toptensoftware.com/blog/posts/17/high-quality-image-resampling-in-monolinux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ImageMagick is both a command line tool and a library with high quality interpolation and antialiasing algorithms.